# How can I use a javascript library like Angular.js on the Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

Is the Smartface provide external libraries in order to them on projects?

For example, if I want to use Angular.js in my Project, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Smartface App Studio can use any JavaScript code or frameWork without DOM.

Also, there is an ongoing development about plugin support for community. You can also use Obj-C , JAVA , C++ libraries in your applicaiton.

You can also check the link below which uses UnderScore frameWork in Smartface App Studio;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/get-started/sample-smartface-code-project-kitchen-sink/

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/get-started/reusable-sample-dynamic-codes-kitchen-sink-part-2/

And you can check the roadMap for more information about plugin development and more;

http://www.smartface.io/roadmap/